# What species is this plant?

Tags: identification, flowers

I'm doing taxonomy project and unsure what species is this plant. Based on research I've done, it's Asian pigeonwings or *Clitoria ternatea* to be exact. I just need confirmation of this plant to move onto next part of the project.

[image]

Comment: Not sure your ID is correct - the leaves seem somewhat large compared to the size of the flower, and altogether too pointed to be Clitoria ternatea, which has a more rounded tip. We also can't see inside the flower, which is important for this plant. Does it grow as a shrub, or does it creep or climb, this plant? What part of the world is it growing in?

Comment: I confirm Bamboo. From internet, it seems that Clitoria ternatea is a Fabaceae, with pinnate leaves (odd pinnate). Your example is clearly a simple leave (opposite leaves). I would go to other families, e.g. Campanulaceae.

Answer (score 1):

Having already said this plant is not Clitoria ternatea because the leaves are too large and pointed, if there's a yellow throat inside the flower, I'm pretty sure it's actually Thunbergia erecta, image here https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Thunbergia_erecta_(3).JPG

There is an obvious waviness to the leaf edges in your image - the trouble is, because it's a cut stem, that waviness could have been down to drying out, but Thunbergia does have the same waviness to the leaf edges. It's a climbing perennial plant native to western Africa, belonging to the Acanthaceae family.